# Import custom FxCop rules to sonar

Tags: .net, sonarqube, fxcop

Please help me,

Custom assembly : 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft FxCop 1.35\Rules\my\DOTNET.dll

Rules file :
D:\SONAR\extensions\rules\fxcop\DOTNET.xml

I click on restore profile and backup this file: export.xml -- after import is 0 rules

What is wrong?

Thanks for help.
David Molcan

Here is DOTNET.xml

```
<rules>
<rule key="DOTNETCodeWritingGuidlinesForClassesFinalizerWithIDisposable">
<name>
<![CDATA[ La méthode doit avoir une casse correct. ]]>
</name>
<configKey>
<![CDATA[
DOTNETCodeWritingGuidlinesForClassesFinalizerWithIDisposable@C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft FxCop 1.35\Rules\my\DOTNET.dll
]]>
</configKey>
<category name="Maintainability"/>
<description>
<![CDATA[ La méthode doit avoir une casse correct. ]]>
</description>
</rule>
</rules>
```

Here is export.xml

```
<!--  Generated by SonarQube  -->
<profile>
    <name>Sonar way2</name>
    <language>cs</language>
<FxCopProject Version="1.36">
<ProjectOptions>
<SharedProject>True</SharedProject>
<SaveMessages>
<Project NewOnly="False" Status="Active, Excluded"/>
<Report NewOnly="False" Status="Active"/>
</SaveMessages>
<ProjectFile Deterministic="True" SaveByRuleGroup="" DefaultRuleCheck="True" DefaultTargetCheck="True" Compress="True"/>
<EnableMultithreadedLoad>True</EnableMultithreadedLoad>
<EnableMultithreadedAnalysis>True</EnableMultithreadedAnalysis>
<SourceLookup>True</SourceLookup>
<AnalysisExceptionsThreshold>10</AnalysisExceptionsThreshold>
<RuleExceptionsThreshold>1</RuleExceptionsThreshold>
<Spelling Locale="en-US"/>
<OverrideRuleVisibilities>False</OverrideRuleVisibilities>
<CustomDictionaries SearchProjectDir="True" SearchUserProfile="True" SearchFxCopDir="True"/>
<IgnoreGeneratedCode>False</IgnoreGeneratedCode>
</ProjectOptions>
<Rules>
<RuleFiles>
<RuleFile AllRulesEnabled="False" Enabled="True" Name="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft FxCop 1.35\Rules\my\DOTNET.dll">
<Rule Enabled="True" Name="DOTNETCodeWritingGuidlinesForClassesFinalizerWithIDisposable" SonarPriority="major"/>
</RuleFile>
</RuleFiles>
</Rules>
</FxCopProject>
</profile>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FxCop 1.35 is very old and no longer officially supported by the SonarQube C# plugin, even though it *might* still work. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2010/03/26/how-to-write-custom-static-code-analysis-rules-and-integrate-them-into-visual-studio-2010.aspx for details on how to implement FxCop custom rules.

Since the C# 3.2 plugin, custom FxCop rules are supported again. To use them, simply copy the rule template "Template for custom FxCop rules" (key `CustomRuleTemplate`) as many times as required and specify the `CheckId` of each of your custom rume.

If you are still using version 2.1 of the C# plugin, you might want to read http://docs.codehaus.org/x/EIBMDg before upgrading to 3.x.